# jQuery AJAX - Creating DOM elements

Tags: jquery

I am having this function in jQuery where I'm getting new posts with AJAX and PHP. And then creating a new div and appending the post to it.

Here is my code:

```
function getMorePosts(latestPost){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/includes/classes/handler.php?do=getMorePosts",
        data: "&latestPost="+latestPost,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
                $('#addUpdate textarea').val('');
                $('<div id="newPosts"></div>').insertAfter('.myDeskAdd');
                $(data).prependTo('#newPosts');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Now, data is all of HTML code from my handler.php. Everything works, it's appending and I can see the result on the screen. And it's correct - nice!

But here is my problem: 
When it's added to the screen, it's like I cant 'use' the DOM elements. For example: I have an image which I can click, and then it has to call an alert from jQuery, but it's not. And all other jQuery effects bound to the dom elements created doesn't work.

Those elements not working DOES work if I press F5.

I have tried `html()`, `prepend()`, `append()` and so on.

Comment: You have to re-bind event handlers after the content is appended into the page. Or look at jQuery's `on` to delegate events.

Comment: How do I rebind the event handlers? I'll take a look at the On

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for all dynamic content (loaded from ajax), bind methods using **jQuery on**. Then it should work

instead of this,

```
 $(".imageClass").click(function(){
    alert($(this).html());    
 });
```

Use this

```
 $(".yourContainerDiv").on("click", ".imageClass", function(event){
     alert($(this).html());    
 });
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Would I completely remove my normal click() method, and replace it with .on() instead? Or should I use on() in my function getMorePosts(). ?

Comment: But, I don't need to bind handlers to elements when the star img is clicked. I need to bind the handlers to newly loaded elements by the ajax function. How would I do that?

Comment: If you want to bind only to the newly loaded content, bind that in your ajax success event after you prepend it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with the appropriate parameters to bind events to the newly added DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use event delegation, event handlers only apply to elements that exist when the code to bind them is run, so any dynamically added elements later on won't have the event handlers bound, and your functionality won't work.

Take a look at the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7+) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (prior to jQuery 1.7) functions for more information on event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

When elements are dynamically generated, they will not attach to previous event handlers.

You have to use .[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to delegate the event handlers.

*Example:*

```
$(".yourmajoreventhandler").on('click', function() {
    //do your stuff
});
```

*Delegation Example:*

```
$("body").on('click', ".yourmajoreventhandler", function() {
    //do your stuff
});
```

Now, every time, you generate a element with class `yourmajoreventhandler` the above function will run.

Comment: That usage of `.on()` doesn't set up event delegation, which is needed for dynamically generated content.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, It does. Why don't you do you research before commenting. `$(element).on("click", "selectors", function() {});`

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/TSqbs/1/) demo from my another answer to prove my point

Comment: My comment was 16 minutes ago, well before you edited your answer to include the correct usage for event delegation - at that time, my comment was valid because your answer was incorrect. The attitude is unnecessary.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, What part of `example` dont you understand? I linked the doc to show the entire usage. Since when, do i have to code entire code for the OP to get him started now.

Comment: Your original answer - the one that I commented on, the one that received a downvote (from somebody other than myself), and the one that you subsequently deleted - didn't provide any examples of **event delegation** using `.on()`, only regular event binding, which will do nothing for dynamically added elements. Providing a basic example is perfectly adequate, provided it's an example of the **correct usage** (which, for the final time, it wasn't **when I made my comment**). Is that clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

How are the events bound to the DOM elements that you are adding? Are they attributes of the element or are you using jQuery to bind them? If it's the former, you'll need to post more code but I'm guess it's the latter in which case you will need to use [jQuery's on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind your events.

When you bind an event it only applies to the elements that currently exist. They don't get propagated to new elements. Using the `on()` method works around this by binding to all new elements as well.